# matlab thinning algorithm java implementation

Tags: java, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I wanted to use bwmorph(thin) function of matlab in java. I found algorithm on matlab page:
http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html

and wrote in java: (for image saving, I use openCV Mat data structure, basicly 2d array)

```
 package pbl;

 import org.opencv.core.CvType;
 import org.opencv.core.Mat;


public class Thinning {

boolean B[][];

public Mat doJaniThinning(Mat Image) {
 B = new boolean[Image.rows()][Image.cols()];
 boolean [][] B_ = new boolean[Image.rows()][Image.cols()];
    for(int i=0; i<Image.rows(); i++) 
        for(int j=0; j<Image.cols(); j++) 
                    B[i][j] = (Image.get(i, j)[0]>100?false:true); //not a mistake, in matlab first invert and then morph

   for(int iter = 0; iter < 1000; iter++) {
            //Iteration #1
            for(int i=0; i<Image.rows(); i++) 
                for(int j=0; j<Image.cols(); j++) 
                    if(B[i][j] && G1(i, j) && G2(i, j) && G3(i, j)) B_[i][j] = false;
                    else B_[i][j] = B[i][j];;

            for(int i=0; i<Image.rows(); i++) 
                for(int j=0; j<Image.cols(); j++) B[i][j] = B_[i][j];
            //Iteration #2
            for(int i=0; i<Image.rows(); i++) 
                for(int j=0; j<Image.cols(); j++) 
                    if(B[i][j] && G1(i, j) && G2(i, j) && G3_(i, j)) B_[i][j] = false;
                    else B_[i][j] = B[i][j];


            for(int i=0; i<Image.rows(); i++) 
                for(int j=0; j<Image.cols(); j++) B[i][j] = B_[i][j];
    }


    Mat r = new Mat(Image.rows(), Image.cols(), CvType.CV_32SC1);

    for(int i=0; i<Image.rows(); i++) 
            for(int j=0; j<Image.cols(); j++) {
                int[] a = new int[1];
                a[0] = B[i][j]?255:0;
                r.put(i, j, a);
       }


        return r;
}

public boolean x(int a, int i, int j) {
    try {
    switch(a) {
        case 1:
            return B[i+1][j];

        case 2:
            return B[i+1][j+1];

        case 3:
            return B[i][j+1];

        case 4:
            return B[i-1][j+1];

        case 5:
            return B[i-1][j];

        case 6:
            return B[i-1][j-1];

        case 7:
            return B[i][j-1];

        case 8:
            return B[i+1][j-1];


    }
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean G1(int i, int j) {
    int X = 0;
    for(int q=1; q<=4; q++) {
        if(!x(2*q-1, i, j) && (x(2*q, i, j) || x(2*q+1, i, j))) X++;
    }
    return X==1;
}

public boolean G2(int i, int j) {
  int m = Math.min(n1(i, j), n2(i, j));
  return (m==2 || m==3);
}

public int n1(int i, int j) {
    int r = 0;
    for(int q=1; q<=4; q++) 
        if(x(2*q-1, i, j) || x(2*q, i, j)) r++;
    return r;
}

public int n2(int i, int j) {
    int r = 0;
    for(int q=1; q<=4; q++) 
        if(x(2*q, i, j) || x(2*q+1, i, j)) r++;
    return r;
}

public boolean G3(int i, int j) {
    return !(x(2, i, j) || x(3, i, j) || !x(8, i, j) && x(1, i, j));
}

public boolean G3_(int i, int j) {
    return !(x(6, i, j) || x(7, i, j) || !x(4, i, j) && x(5, i, j));
}





}
```

and it didn't work.
Image trying to thin:

[image]

Matlab result:

[image]

My java code result:

[image]

Don't know what to do more, any help?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I Corrected G3 and G3_, but now I get:

[image]

Which is still different from matlab one, bit different but I need exactly that one

Comment: P.S. For openCV findcountours, MATLAB version is perfect, but my implementation of matlab thinning is disaster, thats why I want exactly the same

Comment: Were you able to find your bug eventually?

Answer (score 2):

i think the G3 and G3_ is wrong:

```
public boolean G3(int i, int j) {
    return (x(2, i, j) || x(3, i, j) || !x(8, i, j)) && x(1, i, j);
}

public boolean G3_(int i, int j) {
    return (x(6, i, j) || x(7, i, j) || !x(4, i, j)) && x(5, i, j);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but there still should be some problem, answer is still bit different, gives huge difference in openCV analysis

Comment: I don't see another error. I would recommend you to use some open source implementation of the algorithm and compare it step by step. If you are used to matlab, i would use the octave implementation. The syntax is nearly identical, the function is named bwmorph.m as well.